# minitoc start at section level?

Tags: minitoc

There are other posts that ask about how to modify how deep / what minitoc displays. This is not that question.

I have a very large document that is a book class and was previously using minitoc at each chapter. The document recently got bigger, requiring for all previous chapters to be demoted to sections (if that makes sense? sort of like having two books in the same document)

So now I have something like

```
\chapter{this is a really big chapter, used to be the whole document}
\section{this was a chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
\section{this was another chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
\section{this was one more chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
\chapter{this is a new chapter (but will have a lot of content that used to be chapters)}
\section{this was a chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
```

The issue I am having is that now minitoc shows everything from all previous "chapters" because minitoc stops listing things at the next chapter instance (and they are now all sections)

so how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to faq 9 in section 2 of [minitoc doc](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/minitoc.pdf), section tocs are not allowed in book class:

> How to do minitocs (minilofs and minilots) at levels other than chapter? 
>   Here also, some redesign is needed. From version #15, there are parttocs,
>   partlofs and partlots for the part level in book-like and article like 
>   documents, secttocs, sectlofs and sectlots for the section level in 
>   article-like documents.

If you are using book class, probably using `\part` instead of big chapters suits what you want:

```
\documentclass[...]{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
...

\part{this is a really big chapter, used to be the whole document}
\chapter{this was a chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
\chapter{this was another chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
\chapter{this was one more chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
\part{this is a new chapter (but will have a lot of content that used to be chapters)}
\chapter{this was a chapter previously}
\minitoc
...
```